# VAR equation-by-equation and variance-

Tags: least-squares, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression

It is written that the estimation of reduced form VAR is possible via equation-by-equation OLS.
How does the reduced form errors variance-covariance matrix is estimated in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found, $\hat{\Omega}=\dfrac{\sum_{2}^{T} \hat{e_{t}}\hat{e_{t}}'}{T}$

Comment: If you believe this resolves your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.